# modify json response in php?

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am newbie in php m creating web service for my colors reponse. It works great on my web application as i can fetch data from it easily now in android m stuck.

I have response like that.

```
{

        "#CCCCCC":[43.2,"SILVER"], 
        "#424153":[42.6,"GREY"],
        "#999999":[13.7,"LIGHT GREY"]
}
```

I want to change this like that.

```
{
   "colors":
            [
               {
                 "hex" : "#CCCCCC",
                 "percentgae" : "43.2",
                 "name" : "silver"
               },
               {
                 "hex" : "#424153",
                 "percentgae" : "43.2",
                 "name" : "grey"
               },
               {
                 "hex" : "#999999",
                 "percentgae" : "13.2",
                 "name" : "light grey"
               }
            ]
}
```

can u tell me how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Yes, please update with the code you have so far to generate the array structure you have currently.

Comment: i have two dimensional array which return like that "#CCCCCC" => "23" and i have an array which return name of hex value "#CCCCCC" => "Grey". I merge both array using $result = array_merger_recursive ($array1,$array2). Which give me array like that (Array [#CCCCCC]=> array(0 => 23 , 1= > Grey)  ). now i convert $result to json using json_encode($result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the next function

```
<?php

function format($json) {
    $colors = json_decode($json);
    $result = [];
    foreach ($colors as $color => $attributes) {
        $result[] = [
            'hex'         => $color,
            'percentagae' => $attributes[0],
            'name'        => $attributes[1]
        ];
    }

    return json_encode([ 'colors' => $result]);
}

$json        = '{ "#CCCCCC":[43.2,"SILVER"], "#424153":[42.6,"GREY"], "#999999":[13.7,"LIGHT GREY"] }';
$expectation = '{"colors":[{"hex":"#CCCCCC","percentagae":43.2,"name":"SILVER"},{"hex":"#424153","percentagae":42.6,"name":"GREY"},{"hex":"#999999","percentagae":13.7,"name":"LIGHT GREY"}]}';
$response    = format($json);

if ($response != $expectation) {
    throw new Exception('FAIL');
}

echo 'SUCCESS';
```

Comment: It helps me to get my required result. so i accept ur ans : cheers